# Curl command works, but httparty request gives 403

Tags: httparty

I have a curl command that makes a POST request, and returns with the correct response:

```
curl --data 'apiKey=someKey&apiSecureKey=someSecureKey&apiFunctionName=update&apiFunctionParams={"id”:”777”,”user_password":"password","invalid_login_attempts":"0","active_flag":"1"}' https://api-server.com/api-path/file.php
```

Also, when using Postman, the request works if I check the "form-data" button and paste the same four parameters that are in the curl command above into the body of the Postman request.  If I check the "x-www-form-urlencoded" button in Postman, I get a 403 response (see below), so that makes me think it is a header issue.

I need to duplicate this request using httparty.  Here is my attempt:

```
options = {
body: {
    apiKey: 'someKey',
    apiSecureKey: 'someSecureKey',
    apiFunctionName: 'update',
    apiFunctionParams: '{"id”:”777”,”user_password":"password","invalid_login_attempts":"0","active_flag":"1"}',
}
}

response = HTTParty.post("https://api-server.com/api-path/file.php", options)
```

This request gives me a 403 repsonse code:

```
{"success":false,"response":"403","responseDesc":"Forbidden. Request is missing an API permission code.","params":{"id":"777","user_password":"password","invalid_login_attempts":"0","active_flag":"1"}}
```

If I try to add a header, such as:

```
options = {
  headers: {'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'},
  body: {
      apiKey: '20a030e47a28',
      apiSecureKey: '3a4e409e0c9f0e72e697fc288a88d751',
      apiFunctionName: 'update',
      apiFunctionParams: '{"id":"603","user_password":"password","invalid_login_attempts":"0","active_flag":"1"}',
  }

response = HTTParty.post("https://beta.fxptouch.com/classes/interface/user_profile.php", options)
```

I get a nil response.

Comment: I was able to get this working by changing the "Content-Type" to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", so the line above in "options" should be:

headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},